# c++: strategies for stability of floating point arithmetic

Tags: c++, math, floating-accuracy, stability, numerical-stability

Can anyone recommend any C++ libraries/routines/packages that contain strategies for maintaining the stability of various floating point operations?

Example:  suppose you would like to sum across a vector/array of one million `long double` in the unit interval (0,1), and that each number is of about the same order of magnitude.  Naively summing `for (int i=0;i<1000000;++i) sum += array[i];`   is unreliable - for large enough `i`, `sum` will be of a much larger order of magnitude than `array[i]`, and so `sum += array[i]` would be equivalent to `sum += 0.00`.
(Note: the solution to this example is a binary summing strategy.)

I deal with sums and products of thousands/millions of miniscule probabilities.  I am using the arbitrary-precision library `MPFRC++` with a 2048 bit significand, but the same concerns  still apply.

I am chiefly concerned with:

1. Strategies for accurately summing many numbers (e.g. above Example).
2. When is multiplication and division potentially unstable?  (If I want to normalize a large array of numbers, what should my normalization constant be?  The smallest value?  The largest? A median?)

Answer (score 6):

Binary summation doesn't *guarantee* accurate result. The most reliable (albeit slower) method is to use [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). [Boost.Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/accumulators.html) has an implementation of the above and much more.

Multiplication and division stability: unless you get to denormalized floats they don't suffer from the same problems as summation and substraction. In fact the error of multiplication is *at most* 0.5 ulp (units last place).

> ... what should my normalization constant be?

What do you mean by 'normalize'? It depends on the [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) you use. Possible candidates: use the maximum absolute value in the array, or any other generalized mean. (Other choices you listed do not work since they may be zero even for non-zero array.)

Comment: By "normalize", I mean:

At step X, I have a set of miniscule-but-non-zero probabilities.  At step X+1, I will multiply these numbers by even more miniscule probabilities.  According to the details of my mathematical model, I am allowed to multiply the numbers at step X by any constant (i.e. normalize) before moving to step X+1.  This has the practical benefit of helping avoid underflow.

Comment: @CycoMatto: then you should multiply by a power of two once in a while. The only way to avoid underflow/overflow is to guarantee that the ratio between the largest and the smallest numbers is representable with the floating points at hand (if not, you can't do anything).

Comment: Alternatively store their logarithms and use summation. Can't say  about the stability of this approach though.

Comment: Why a power of 2?   Currently, I am multiplying by the inverse of the smallest number at step X - this way, the numbers are all >= 1.  Multiplying by probabilities at step X+1 will then "drag the numbers back toward 0".  Right?

Comment: I was also thinking of multiplying by some nice power of 10.  But I suppose a power of 2 makes more sense given that numbers are stored in binary.

Comment: You use a kind of "inverse transformation". This rule may help: "The specific transformation used depends on the extent of the deviation from normality. If the distribution differs moderately from normality, a square root transformation is often the best. A log transformation is usually best if the data are more substantially non-normal. An inverse transformation should be tried for severely non-normal data." 
http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/analysis/regression_intro.htm

Comment: @SChepurin thank you, but I can't use any transformation - only constants. (constants will "cancel" in any division and can traverse sums, and this will not affect the mathematics).

Comment: @CycoMatto: multiplying or dividing by a power of two does not degrade accuracy *at all*. I just want to note that if you have the concerns of underflow, and you normalize it as you described, then you also have to think about possible overflows during normalization.